# On Form Submit event object giving error: "TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined."

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to set up a basic script that emails on form submission, with the (pie in the sky) goal of creating an email that will send an attached outlook calendar invite. Here is my script.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var userName = e.values[1];
  var userEmail = e.values[2];
  var subject = "Form Submitted";
  var message = "Thank you, " + userName + " for your submission";
  MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, message)
}
```

[Here's an image of my trigger situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCXrb.jpg)

The error I get is: "TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined."

[Here's an image of the Execution transcript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQMh6.jpg)

Here's where I've been:
[Google Scripts for Sheets - onEdit and "source"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28031432/google-scripts-for-sheets-onedit-and-source)

I promise I'm not running in the editor - I'm filling out the form and submitting. I know I have to be doing something stupid, but I can't figure out what it is. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm guessing that your code is in a project bound to the Form?  There is no `values` property of the event object sent to a script bound to the Form.  If you set up the code to be in a project bound to a spreadsheet, *then* you can use the `values` property.  If you don't want to use a script bound to a spreadsheet, you'll need to use `e.response` which gets a Form response.  [Apps Script documentation - Form response](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response)  Then you'll need to get the values out of the Response.

Comment: You are guessing correctly. I tried to substitute "e.response" and (e.responses) for "e.values", but I got an undefined error - "Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot read property "1" from undefined. "

I then moved the script over to the spreadsheet as opposed to the form, and the script worked. Is there a best practice as far as where the script should bound?

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I don't know of any best practice for this.  I would mainly make the decision based on "ease of access" to whatever I need.  For you, it's a lot easier to put the "On Form Submit" trigger into the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "On Submit" trigger is running from a script bound to the **Form**, and the `values` property is not available to the event object sent to the **Form**.  The `values` property is only available to the event object sent to the **spreadsheet**.

See Event Objects:
[Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the form submission properties, you need to treat your event object e as a FormResponse object.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var responses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  for( var i=0; i < responses.length; i++ ) {
    console.log(responses[i].getItem().getTitle() + " : " + responses[i].getResponse());
  }
}
```